# Speeding up browsing in an XPS file

Tags: c#, xps

Our software includes rather large XPS file (70 full color pages) which is shown in a `System.Windows.Controls.DocumentViewer`. The file is loaded like this:

```
using System.Windows.Xps.Packaging;

var document = new XpsDocument(path, FileAccess.Read);
// The DocumentViewer binds to the property DocumentSource
this.DocumentSource = document.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
```

Browsing between pages takes several seconds on a pretty beefy computer (Intel i7 4790, 16GB ram). Making reading the document a painful process.

Since we use only built-in functions to load and display the XPS file I cannot think of much on the code side to improve performance. (Though tips are welcome!) But maybe the XPS file itself can be optimized.  For PDF files there are a lot of optimizer which greatly reduce the size and complexity of PDF files. Are there any tools or techniques available that do this with XPS files? I'm also not sure if the entire XPS file is loaded, or if parts are loaded on-demand. Maybe there is an option to do more agresive pre-loading or even loading the entire document?

Comment: Does the file by any chance contain lots of large high res images?

Comment: @Liam the XPS file is converted from a PDF file via Window's built in XPS printer. the PDF file (made in InDesign) contains high res images. I'm not sure how the XPS printer handles those. Although the manual contains 70 pages its only 10MB in size.